# I changed the syntax in flask-qrcode but couldn't

Tags: javascript, python, flask, qr-code

i use code in https://github.com/marcoagner/Flask-QRcode/tree/master/sample_application
but I had an error with the {{}} sign

```
<img src="{{ qrcode("Load icon image from static folder.", error_correction='H', icon_img='icon.jpg') }}">
```

I changed it to

```
var test = "hello eve."

<img src="{{ qrcode("+test+", error_correction='H', icon_img='icon.jpg') }}">
```

It didn't work and it failed, I searched the internet a lot but I still didn't know what it was

Comment: What exact error do you have, it does not render this part or just render it as _it is_?

Comment: @funnydman I want it printed as "hello eve." but it prints "test"